# How to pass a list through pages in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am currently working at an UWP app. I have a `ListView` with check boxes. I want to pass each element of the list—assuming it's checked—to another page. This is what I've tried so far:

MainPage:

```
ArrayList selected = new ArrayList();
private void chk_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    string item = checkbox.DataContext.ToString();
    selected.Add(item);

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), selected);

}
```

Second Page:

```
ArrayList s = new ArrayList();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    s = e.selected;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including the code, that's really useful. In addition, it would be helpful to include what's not working, or what concept you know is missing but are struggling to implement.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time :) I don't know to pass a list through 2 pages. Especially on the OnNavigatedto() , basically i am struggling with syntax and i don't even know if it s the right approach.

Comment: When you trying to get the parameter in the second page, you need to get [NavigationEventArgs.Parameter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.parameter?view=winrt-18362#Windows_UI_Xaml_Navigation_NavigationEventArgs_Parameter) because there is no selected property in the NavigationEventArgs object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way to pass params is right, but when using the param, you can do like this.

```
ArrayList s = new ArrayList();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    s = e.Parameter as ArrayList;
    if(s != null)
    {
        //to do
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

For more info, see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#3-pass-information-between-pages)

Comment: Do you know how can i do the same thing but without actually changing the page?

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain it, without actually changing the page?

Comment: when i select a checkbox it immediatly goes to the other page, i want to be able to check more checkboxes

Comment: Yes, but you can't do the navigate thing in the `Checked` event, cause this event happens immediatelly when you check an box. You can use a `Button` to called `Submit`, then after you checked all options, use `Button_Clicked` event to navigate and pass params.